# Which is the correct "code/word" for Language Neutral?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I read an [article from Gábor Hojtsy](http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2011-jan-31/drupal-7039s-new-multilingual-systems-part-4-node-translation) where he says:

> Language neutral uses the language code **'und'**, which means **undefined**
>   and is specified to be used for such cases by the ISO 639 standard.

But when you go to read the [ISO 639](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes) you can find:

> **und**, for **"undetermined"**;

And you can find inside Drupal the **"Language Neutral"**

I ask the question because I'm writing a module where I need to have a word to identify the nodes that don't have a defined language. So, which is the word to use, Neutral, Undefined or Undetermined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Drupal constant LANGUAGE_NONE api documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_NONE/7) `Und` stands for *undetermined* and in Drupal 8 it is called [LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Language!LanguageInterface.php/constant/LanguageInterface%3A%3ALANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED/8)

Answer (score 1):

They are generally referred to as "language neutral nodes" to the user. So that is how your module should call them too.
They are called "und(efined)" by developers only.